# How to remove element from a list while iterating?

Tags: python

```
my_list = ['aa', 'aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']
```

my_list is sorted by element length. What I want to do:

for each element from left to right, if an element is part of another element, then remove the shorter element. For example, since 'aa' is part of 'aab', I want to remove 'aa'.

```
length = len(my_list)
for i in range(0, length):
    v = my_list[i]
    j = i+1
    if j<length:
        if v in my_list[j]:
            my_list.pop(i)
```

This loop changed the original list so it breaks.

This version seem working:

```
length = len(my_list)
new_list = my_list.copy()
for i in range(0, length):
    v = my_list[i]
    for j in range(i+1, length):
        if v in my_list[j]:
            new_list.pop(i)
```

Comment: a short ans: you shouldn't modify the original list. you should simply create a new list based on the condition.

Comment: @Mox, it looks like I need 2 loops to do that.

Comment: When you get to `'abcde'`, should `'b'` be removed, since the `'aab'` was replaced with `'b'`? Or should be be unmodified because `'abcde'` does not contain `'aab'`?

Comment: If not contained, then no removal.

Comment: @marlon, for your case you need double loops, but you may use my deleted ans on how to do it in a pythonic way.

Comment: @marlon, use copy.deepcopy()

Comment: I see no need for deepcopy. The reason to avoid modifying the list that you are iterating over is that it messes up the indexing. Modifying a list that you have copied with a simple copy is sufficient to avoid this.

Comment: @Mox, regular copy doesnt work here?

Comment: @marlon, oh this works too. just did a google search on it.

Comment: There could be reasons _not_ to use deepcopy, if the list contains references to other objects that you wish to modify, or that are expensive to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify a list that you are iterating over, which you are effectively doing here.  So you would create a new list `my_list_out = my_list[:]` and modify that instead of inside the loop.

Some other bits of unsolicited advice about your code (other than suggesting any clever one-liners to solve this):

```py
length = len(my_list)
for i in range(0, length):
    v = my_list[i]
    j = i+1
    if j<length:
        if v in my_list[j]:
            my_list.pop(i)
```

- the indentation on the `for` statement needs fixing
- with the `enumerate` function, you can replace this sort of construct:

```
        for i in range(0, length):
            v = my_list[i]
```

with this:

```
        for i, v in enumerate(my_list[:length]):
```

or in this case, because you set `length = len(my_list)`, just:

```
        for i, v in enumerate(my_list):`
```

- you are not really doing anything on the last iteration, so you might as well loop up to the previous one and then avoid the `if j<length` test

Putting these together, plus also the fact that (as discussed in comments below) the requirement is to pop the element where the string is part of *any* later element and not only the immediately adjacent one, gives:

```
my_list = ['aa', 'aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']

my_list_out = my_list[:]
length = len(my_list)
for i, v in enumerate(my_list[ : length-1]):
    for v2 in my_list[i+1 :]:
        if v in v2:
            my_list_out.pop(i)
            break
my_list = my_list_out

print(my_list)
```

In this case, in the inner loop the index is not required, so the loop is simply over the values (`for v2 in ...`).

Running this gives:

```
$ python3 test.py
['aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']
```

Comment: @marlon It gives `['aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']`. What result were you expecting?

Comment: It needs 2 loops See this input: my_list = ['aa', 'ab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']. 'aa' wan't removed

Comment: @marlon I don't know what code you are running, but if you run your original assignment (`my_list = ['aa', 'aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']`) followed by my code (either unindented, or with `if True:` before it to avoid having to unindent) followed by `print(my_list)`, then it reports `['aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']` as I said.

Comment: @marlon I have updated the example to show what output the complete program gives when you run it.

Comment: Yes, the original data works, but the generic version could be that the two element may not be adjancent to each other.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear to me. Okay fine, I will suggest a revised version.

Comment: @marlon Before I do that, please can you clarify whether elements that are part of an _earlier_ element should also be removed, for example if the original list was `['aab', 'deff', 'aa']`, should the `aa` be removed?

Comment: The data is already sorted by length. So it won't happen that way. I sorted to make the removal eaiser.

Comment: @marlon Yes you're right, I missed that point. I have now updated the example to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @marlon Just edited it again. Please make sure that you are running the version that contains the `break` statement. In case the reason for the `break` is not obvious, it avoids problems if there are more than one later element containing `v`; as soon as the first is encountered, it exits from the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier when you process the input list in the reversed order and the reverse the result.

Use the following code (printouts for demonstration only):

```
out = []
for it in reversed(my_list):
    if any(it in s for s in out):
        print(f'{it} - drop')
    else:
        out.append(it)
        print(f'{it} - keep')
out = list(reversed(out))
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['aa', 'aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']
list_str = str(my_list) # "['aa', 'aab', 'aaa', 'deff', 'abcde']"
new_list = my_list.copy()
next_ptr = 1  # for the beginning "["
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    next_ptr += 4 + len(my_list[i]) # 4 is for two single quotation('), one comma(,) and one space
    if my_list[i] in list_str[next_ptr:]:
        new_list.pop(i)
my_list = new_list
```